# Disable Samsung Browser's Pop-Up Player Feature

Tags: android, html, html5-video, samsung-browser

I have a website where users can watch videos (I used [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement)).
In Samsung Browser, when entering full-screen mode, there is a button that allows to float the video, and watch it while scrolling.
It is also possible to use Samsung Browser's Video Assistant for that as well ([video](https://youtu.be/IEdoDl9wPLE?t=597)).

I wish to disable this feature, but couldn't find anything related.

Your help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. SamSung browser has this Video element by default . disablign this mean one need to disable samsung browser by default.
2. You can do a work on HTML pages by explicitly disabling any external app in accessing you video content , this way the samsung browser would be able to pick you video content into its plugin.
3. Use Content Locker for HTML web pages which can disable samsung browser from picking up your video content on your webpage.